# CSS Hover on list item seems to be affecting all list items within ul

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm having an issue on my menu items. 
I have my menu items styled so whenever I hover over a list item, it dims the hovered item.
However, whenever I hover on one list item, it seems to be affecting and dimming all list items.

I narrowed down the problem. It works perfectly fine when my menu-bar-container div is positioned relative. However, I want this menu-bar-container div to be fixed.

Anyone know what seems to be the issue? Appreciate the help in advance.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="menu-bar-container"> 

  <h1> GENE WONG OFFICIAL PAGE </h1>

    <div class="clear"> </div>

        <div id="menu-bar-2"> 
            <ul>
              <li class="fade"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
              <li class="fade"><a href="index.html">NEWS</a></li>
              <li class="fade"><a href="bio.html">BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
              <li class="fade"><a href="index.html">MEDIA</a></li>
              <li class="fade"><a href="index.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
              <li class="fade active"><a href="gear.html">GEAR</a></li>
              <li class="fade"><a href="index.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
#menu-bar-container {
    background: url(images/hp/header-bg.png);
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2F2F2F;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
} 

#menu-bar-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 32px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#menu-bar-2 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 4px;
    height: 30px;
}

#menu-bar-2 li {
    float:left;
}

#menu-bar-2 li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    top: 10px;
    color: white;
}

#menu-bar-2 li.active a {
   color:#E20000;
} 


.fade {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade:hover {
    opacity: .7;
}
```

Comment: Your provided CSS doesn't actually show any `:hover` states, but your problem indicates that a `:hover` effect is not functioning as expected.  Can you offer clarification?

Comment: My apologies, I've added the fade class and hover properties.

What I want to happen on hover over a list item is have that specific list item dim in opacity. 

However, when I am hovering over any list item, all list items are being dimmed (without animation) and then quickly returning to regular opacity. Seems to me all list items are being affected instead of just the hovered item.

Comment: Seems to work as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/t00h7kac/ I'm not certain what you're referring to.

Comment: Problems could be due to an error in the CSS file somewhere else.

Comment: Strange, when i load it on my google chrome browser it seems to do the mentioned problem. I just tried it on Firefox browser and it's working as intended.

Comment: the fiddle I linked to above works fine in Chrome.